# How can I install gtkmm in codeblocks?

Tags: c++

Please guide me to install `gtkmm` in `codeblocks`

I am following this documentation `https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows`

I have installed `msys2` and performed the action

`pacman -S pkg-config`

After that I don't know how to proceed

I want to run a program in CodeBlocks.

Comment: Did you follow the steps after `pacman -S pkg-config`? Did you get an error message there?

Comment: i am not able to understand what should i do now

Comment: Ah, ok. The next step is the part where you test if code using gtkmm compiles. The first line says `//foo.cpp`, which is telling you to create a file with any name, e.g. `foo.cpp`, and paste the code there. Then you are to compile this code using the `g++ ...` line and see if there are error messages or not. If not, you are good to go. The file has to be in the directory where you run the `g++` command.

Comment: sir i have to go for class for 3 hour from now so i willl try it after 3 hour thank u for ur response

Comment: sir when i run that code in codeblocks it  says no such directory found

Comment: sir help me please

Comment: To help you, we need more information. Did you create a file `foo.cpp` with the test program? Did you run the `g++` command in the same directory? What exactly is the error message? Which directory was not found?

Comment: from the start first i downloaded msys2-x86_64-20180531 then i install after installaton one window pop up ,then i run those three command(pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc,pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc,pacman -S pkg-config) it download something,then in codeblock i paste this code and save as Untitled1.cpp ,then in cmd i run it  C:\Users\DSV\Desktop>g++ -o Untitled Untitled1.cpp
Untitled1.cpp:2:19: fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtkmm.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: So your g++ line is missing the part `$(pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 ...`? This part tells the compiler where to find the include files, which explains the error of not being able to find them.

Comment: what should i do now

Comment: The syntax will not work in CMD, you will need to use a MingW bash-like terminal (I don't have MingW installed, don't know how it's called). Then enter the compile command in full, as written in the tutorial (only replacing the file name foo.cpp).

Comment: i have already installed it if i run simple hello world program it works

Comment: i have found gtkmm.h  is there any method to use it in codeblocks,i mean how to link it to codeblock

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install Gtk3 and Gtkmm3, using MSYS2 shell.
I suppose you're on Windows (x64 ?).
Run this commands: 
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3` 
and then: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3`.
The compiler toolchain in CodeBlocks needs to point to MSYS2/migw64 or mingw32 directory. Something like this: `C:\msys64\mingw64`.